# Is there a way to allow a checkbox to be marked only if there is data entered?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an ng-repeater with each row having an input of type checkbox, as well as 3 text fields. I want to allow the checkbox to be selected ONLY if the user enters some text in each of the 3 text fields. If the user tries selecting a checkbox without entering data first, I want to display a warning message.

I am assuming I have to do some checking for the three ng-models (for text fields) is null or undefined or something, but not sure how to do it in the HTML.

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="o in objects">
    <input type="checkbox" class="myClass" ng-click="doSomething(argument)>
    ....
    ....
    <input ng-model="model1">
    <input ng-model="model2">
    <input ng-model="model3">
```

**EDIT:** Found an answer here [AngularJS - Form Custom Validation - Check if at least one input is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261003/angularjs-form-custom-validation-check-if-at-least-one-input-is-empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable them and use `ng-change` to monitor that all 3 of the text inputs have value.

Sample html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.item3"  ng-change="update()"/>

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.model1" ng-disabled="checksDisabled"/>
```

Example Controller

```
.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope){
     $scope.checksDisabled=true;
     var data = $scope.data ={ };
     $scope.update=function(){
        $scope.checksDisabled = !(data.item1 && data.item2 && data.item3);
     }         
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/x2S9KuZPTcv30FVC7j8L?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I decided to go with the route I posted in my edit because its less code, but if something goes wrong I can use this as backup :).

Comment: understood, personally I prefer less crap in the html and also easier to test with variables

Comment: Yeah you are probably right, is doing the check in the html more taxing or in this case is it no issue? Is checking checksDisabled from the ng-disabled any more efficient? or just cleaner

Comment: probably both , the function gets called rarely (events only) and the variable won't change between events