# AngularJS: disable button when input fields are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

I have a dropdown menu, two input text box, and a submit button. I want the submit button to be disabled until dropdown item is selected AND both input boxes are filled. I looked at several examples including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300067/disable-submit-button-when-form-invalid-with-angularjs) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261003/angularjs-form-custom-validation-check-if-at-least-one-input-is-empty) but none of these are working for me. Below is my code. Thanks

```
<form name="myForm">
  Select an option:
  <select id="dropDown" name="dropDown" ng-model="data.dropDown" >
    ** content for dropDown menu, populating it by using Django
  </select>
  From Date:
  <input type="text" id="dateFrom" ng-model="data.date1" />
  To Date:
  <input type="text" id="dateTo" ng-model="data.date2"   />

  <button id="submit" ng-click="submitRequest()" ng-disabled="!(!!data.dropDown && !!data.date1  && !!data.date2)">Submit </button>
</form>
```

I also tried this method below:

```
<form name="myForm">
  Select an option:
  <select id="dropDown" name="dropDown" ng-model="data.dropDown" >
    ** content for dropDown menu, populating it by using Django
  </select>
  From Date:
  <input type="text" id="dateFrom" ng-model="data.date1" required/>
  To Date:
  <input type="text" id="dateTo" ng-model="data.date2" required />
  <button id="submit" ng-click="submitRequest()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit </button>
</form>
```

So initially when the page loads and all fields are empty by default, the `Submit` button is disabled and the problem is that after all three fields are filled, it doesn't get enabled. Thanks

Comment: Did you try this on the button: `ng-disabled="data.dropDown.length < 1 || data.date1.length < 1 || data.date2.length < 1"`? It should work because your models are strings. You should also do data validation in `submitRequest()` afterwards.

Comment: I tried that but the button just stays disabled even after I the fields are filled. Could it be because of the dropdown?

Comment: Here's a Fiddle that works: https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/25802/
Also, provide us with the controller code if you can. Are you declaring scope variables properly?

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, I know what was causing the problem. So for those `dateFrom` and `dateTo` textbox fields, I was using jQuery's `datepicker` UI to create a popup calendar for user to choose date. And when user selects a date, the value of `ng-model` wasn't updated. How do I fix that?

Comment: I'm not really sure if you can bind that like that. Google for JQuery date component in Angular, you should be able to find a solution.

Comment: @AleksandarBencun hi how about md-datepicker how can detect if the datepicker is fill and then button will enable???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your second method works for me (utilizing myForm.$invalid) if I add `required` to the dropdown element. I've created a plunkr you can play with [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OOLKZI6c8A8A13Svm4hR?p=preview).

```
<form name="myForm">
  Select an option:
  <select id="dropDown" name="dropDown" ng-model="data.dropDown" required>
    <option>red</option>
    <option>blue</option>
    <option>green</option>
  </select><br/>
  From Date:
  <input type="text" id="dateFrom" ng-model="data.date1" required/><br/>
  To Date:
  <input type="text" id="dateTo" ng-model="data.date2" required /><br/>
  <button id="submit" ng-click="submitRequest()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Note: I used Angular 1.4 in the plunkr as you did not specify which version of Angular you are working with.

Edit: OP stated that issue was created by using JQuery's datepicker. May I suggest using angular-ui boostrap datepicker? [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/AvfZKQpK3AibexfB0EVt?p=streamer) - [Angular-UI Bootstrap docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you use `ng-disabled="myForm.myName.$pristine"` because pristine will check for each variable inserted in textboxes

please check small example here..
[ng pristine example](http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/6Zjd3/1/)

Comment: I tried this and the button doesn't even become disabled. Do you know of any other solution I can try?